# GEE, reduceRegions vs reduceRegion, User memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping

I am new in GEE.

I am trying to reduce a mean statistics over an image with `reduceRegions`.
I increased `tileScale` to `16` (max value possible), decreased the number of polygons, exported to asset for performing long running operations,
and the error `'User memory limit exceeded'` kept appearing.

Than, I found (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging?hl=en#reduceregion-vs.-reduceregions) map a `reduceRegion` function divides work into smaller tasks. I set `bestEffort` as `true` and `maxPixel` parameter. But still the error keeps appearing. The scale is the only thing I would like to keep, 10 m of res.

The code works if I run it for two polygons but when the number increases I get the error. Do you have any advise?

Here is the link of my script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e1e80f9ca804651b6c1b3a3614d7e483

Comment: In a completely different script, that previously worked perfectly, I'm having the same error.  "User memory limit exceeded". This all started Feb 29th...  Leap year issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merged_image` is probably causing you trouble. It contains 900+ bands, and will require a lot of memory to process. You're probably better off running `reduceRegion()` or `reduceRegions()` on the individual images and then merging the result somehow. Maybe something like this:

```
var oneclassplys = buff.filterMetadata('GWS_GEWAS', 'equals', oneclass)
  .map(function (polygon) {
    return s1_s2_IC.map(function (image) {
      return regionmean(polygon, image)
    })
  }).flatten()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your solution is not running out of memory but i am finding very difficult to merge all properties of all intersected polygons of the same feature collection. i keep this question open. Maybe it is possible with a join or an iteration over the feature collection? my goal is to have a list of polygon with all 933 properties.